# Design Pattern Review

Tags: design-patterns

I have two processes , only differing in the implementation of their processing styles
ex. Process1 - processes the list of items that need to be processed by one way
and Process 2 processes list of items that need to be processed another way

I want to Process a list of items and then have them pass through process 1 and process 2 depending on a particular property of the item.

I then want a combined output of how many items from the list got processed in each style.

I have chosen to use the "Chain of Resp" pattern. I am wondering if this is a good choice

```
Dim proc1 As New Process1
Dim proc2 as New Process2

proc1.nextProcessing(proc2)
For each itm in itmlst
  proc1.ProcessItem(itm)
Next

proc1.DoSomething()
proc2.DoSomething()

--result is an object that resturns the list of items processed by that process.
Dim result1= proc1.EndPRocess()
Dim result2= proc2.EndProcess()
```

Comment: Where is the "chain of resp" part? Am i blind?

Comment: It seems to be OK but more code might change my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I would use write my own `Composite` for the list and give it the following methods:

```
class Composite {
   Composite filter(Filter f);

   void apply(Function f);
}
```

You can separate out the filtering and apply functions which gives you more extensibility options and the composite handles the iteration for you.  The Composite class itself can handle the reporting of the result of applying different filters.

Comment: why is Composite.filter returning a composite of filtered items? Why not just return a list?

Comment: Composite is a wrapper for a list.